# Kafka multiple partitions not getting split among multiple consumers

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka setup running on Linux. I have set the num of partitions in server.properties to 5. I also have set the num of partitions for the topic I am using (let us call it topic1) to 5.

Now, I have 5 consumers (implemented in Java) subscribing to the above topic. I am expecting that all 5 partitions should split the traffic equally among all the 5 consumers.

I tried the following:

1. ensured that the num of partitions is set to 5 at the topic level and in server.properties.
2. I ran to ensure that there are 5 partitions for this topic:

   `kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic topic1 Topic: topic1       TopicId: 4kX9oP3ARA2uHQ1_nVGY-Q PartitionCount: 5       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: Topic: topic1       Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0 Topic: topic1       Partition: 1    Leader: none    Replicas: 1     Isr: 1 Topic: topic1       Partition: 2    Leader: none    Replicas: 2     Isr: 2 Topic: topic1       Partition: 3    Leader: none    Replicas: 3     Isr: 3 Topic: topic1       Partition: 4    Leader: none    Replicas: 4     Isr: 4`
3. I also ran a similar config in another setup with 5 partitions and 5 consumers on a Windows setup. But there, I could see that all 5 consumers are equally getting the data.
4. But on the Linux setup I mentioned above, it always goes to just 1 consumer.

Any inputs on how I can debug this issue? From the Kafka-topics describe output, it is clear that this topic has 5 partitions. But still those 5 partitions are not splitting among the 5 consumers available.

Is there a way to check either via command line or from the Kafka logs, how many partitions are actually used during the test run? If Kafka-topics describe says 5 partitions, does it actually mean that 5 partitions are also getting used when we run a test?

Note that I am running a load test on this machine - with more than 100 users firing data.

Answer (score 2):

> expecting that all 5 partitions should split the traffic equally among all the 5 consumers

That's not how partitioning works.

Your producer (unclear what you are using; Kafka includes its own `producer-perf-test` CLI tool) designates where records arrive. If you gave each record non-null keys, then partitions are computed based on the hash of those values, and there can be overlap causing no partitions to get any records. Only if your producer uses **null keys** does data get round-robined within the **same request**, not "equally distributed over multiple runs"

Use `GetOffsetShell` to check which partitions have data.